# Magento HTTPS working fine expect product page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and I have a problem with SSL.

I am using this `.htaccess` to redirect all links to  **https://**. All Link working fine else product page or you can say Single product page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**For Example:**

when we visit single product page like: https://www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-j3-alypuhelin-2016-dual-sim-musta.html

Then error comes:

> Too Many redirect

Comment: Sounds like there is another redirection rule coming into play. You want to enable RewriteLogging to learn what exactly is going on inside your RewriteEngine

Comment: Sounds like some code on that page is doing its own redirect back to `http:` which your rule would then correct, in an infinite loop. Have a look a the network panel of your browser's debugger. To see what URLs are redirecting and how.

Comment: Thank you all. I fixed it. problem was store view.